# How can I send mongodb data, stats and infos from my DigitalOcean MongoDB database to my Grafana Dashboard without Prometheus?

Tags: mongodb, grafana, monitoring, digital-ocean, dashboard

I'm trying to create a MongoDB Dashboard on Grafana to get all data I need (logs, statistics, queries...). I've seen that I can get all these information with Prometheus (but I can't install it with managed MongoDB Database) so I wander if there is any method to get all the data I need.

I've already used `db.stats();` internal function to get the data but it's not enough.